# Can a web browser use multiple audio sources concurrently?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a computer with multiple audio out ports on the sound card. Can I use the web audio api or something to play different audio source to different output ports?

For example, in a browser, load 3 tracks and send each track to a different audio output port on the sound card.

Comment: would this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282945/can-you-edit-audio-to-play-different-amounts-of-sound-through-the-2-speakers-of

Comment: You can't because the browser does not have this level of hardware access, You can play sounds, where they are played is decided by the OS/browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The channel splitter seems to have more fine grained control of audio channel. I’m not sure if that is what I would need though. One multi channel audio source to multiple monos?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelSplitterNode

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is unrelated to what you want. This is multiple channels of a single audio stream, not multiple output devices.

Comment: Thanks. oops meant to do a comment not answer from the mobile app.